# Trying to implement a zoom function into my game but it wont unzoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, physics

hello im trying to implement a zoom function into my game but when i release my zoom key it wont lerp my FOV back to its original position

```
[Header("Functional Options")]
[SerializeField] private bool canSprint = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canJump = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canCrouch = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canUseHeadbob = true;
[SerializeField] private bool willSlideOnSlopes = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canZoom = true;

[Header("Zoom Parameters")]
[SerializeField] private float timeToZoom = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] private float zoomFOV = 30f;
[SerializeField] private float defaultFOV;

private Coroutine zoomRoutine;

void Awake()
{
    playerCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    defaultYPos = playerCamera.transform.localPosition.y;
    defaultFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (canMove)
    {
        HandleMovementInput();
        HandleMouseLook();

        if (canJump)
        {
            HandleJump();
        }

        if (canCrouch)
        {
            HandleCrouch();
        }

        if (canUseHeadbob)
        {
            HandleHeadbob();
        }

        if(canZoom)
        {
            HandleZoom();
        }

        ApplyFinalMovements();
    }
}

private void HandleZoom()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(zoomKey))
    {
        if(zoomRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
            zoomRoutine = null;
        }

        zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(toggleZoom(true));

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(zoomKey))
        {
            if (zoomRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
                zoomRoutine = null;
            }

            zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(toggleZoom(false));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator toggleZoom(bool isEnter)
{
    float targetFOV = isEnter ? zoomFOV : defaultFOV;
    float startingFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;
    float timeElapsed = 0;

    while(timeElapsed < timeToZoom)
    {
        playerCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(startingFOV, targetFOV, timeElapsed / timeToZoom);
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    playerCamera.fieldOfView = targetFOV;
    zoomRoutine = null;
}
```

Comment: You need to isolate only the camera functions here, it takes time to read such a large function, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i changed it to only the parts where the zoom is being used but im not sure where the problem is so there is still a hefty amount of code sorry

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because your second `if` statement is inside the first `if` statement.
Your code should look like this:

```
private void HandleZoom()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(zoomKey))
    {
        if (zoomRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
            zoomRoutine = null;
        }

        zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(toggleZoom(true));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(zoomKey))
    {
        if (zoomRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
            zoomRoutine = null;
        }

        zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(toggleZoom(false));
    }
}
```